# DB2 with SQLDB node-red select query not returning expected values

Tags: select, db2, node-red

I have a table called users that contains a single column which has 3 rows all with the values "Ron". When running the following query:

```
SELECT "NAME" 
FROM "USER15886"."USERS" 
WHERE NAME = 'Ron'
```

through the dbadmin or node-red I get an empty result when I would expect to return something like:

{NAME: Ron}

Any ideas as to what is going on?

Comment: Please use the debugging output, any warning or errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake with the query that inserts Ron, it in fact inserted "Ron" into the DB. A query for "Ron" returned the correct results.